# IF ELSE IF END gives Unclosed Function error

Tags: lua, pico-8

I am looking at PICO-8 for the first time.

This simple IF statement give me the error "UNCLOSED FUNCTION AT LINE 1".

```
function MYTEST() 
  local x = 1
  if x==1 then
    print("x==1")
  else if x==0 then
    print("x==0")
  end
end
```

I admit the function is of no use but the interpreter won't allow it to run.

Why?

Comment: `elseif` and not `else if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, changing the code from `else if` to `elseif` makes it work.

Alternatively, add an `end` before the first `end`:

```
function MYTEST() 
  local x = 1
  if x==1 then
    print("x==1")
  else if x==0 then
      print("x==0")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  `elseif` was the problem!